# SSH not working on Raspbian

Tags: ssh, linux, raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+

I can't get SSH to work on my newly setup Raspberry Pi 3. Installed a fresh image of Raspbian Stretch Lite.

I am unable to access the machine in the LAN using SSH:

```
pi@domoticz_pi:~ $ ssh 192.168.178.123
Connection reset by 192.168.178.123 port 22
```

The Pi can be pinged succesfully.

Tried the following to get it to work, without any result:

- Put a empty file called "ssh" (without extension) in the boot partition, using a windows machine (the machine I used to write the image to the SD)
- Enable SSH with the GUI many times. `sudo raspi-config`. "Interfacing Options" -> "SSH"
- Write ssh file to the /boot directory. `cd /boot && sudo touch ssh`. Reboot the Pi.
- Restarted the service multiple times: `sudo systemctl restart ssh`

I don't have a clue why this is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: What result do you get if you run on the RPi `sudo systemctl status ssh`?

Comment: Please edit your question and give us the output from `ssh -vvv pi@192.168.178.123`.

Comment: @Fabian, `sudo systemctl status ssh` gave me pointers to the cause of the problem. See my answer.

Comment: Please add the error messages `Could not load host key` and `key_load_public: invalid format` to your question, they are really important and will help other people to find this page in the future. Glad to hear it's solved!

Comment: So there was a residual key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution. See this [blog post](http://yup-the-website-domain-is.mindginative.com/post/raspberrypi-ssh-connection-reset/).

`sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server`

Answer (score 2):

You normally start `ssh` with `user@host` - on Raspbian `pi` is the normal user.

Try `ssh -vvv pi@host` for more diagnostics

Comment: Yes I know, but get the same error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Fabian exactly the UID must be the same. You can have same name with different UID.

Comment: @Fabian if you want to chat with Ingo about his irrelevant comment do it in chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the below if `sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` did not work.

```
$ sudo su  
# vi /etc/hosts.allow  
sshd:ALL  
$ sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Do you have a reason why you think this might help?

Comment: hosts.allow and host.deny are two access control files. When someone tries to connect, access will be provided only if the entered credentials match the one present in hosts.allow file. That is why it should work